# first character can't be dash(-) in expression

Tags: javascript, regex

how to make regular expression when user enter first character is dash(-) it can't allow(user can enter alpha or numeric AS a first character)

but then after 2nd characters onward user can enter alpha,numeric and dash(-)

Comment: It's JavaScript, not java script. It does actually matter

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression might be a bit expensive here. You can simply use `charAt(0)` to grab the first character from your string, then check to see whether it's the `"-"` character like so:

```
var myString = ...

if (myString.charAt(0) === "-")
  // Do this if true
else
  // Do this if false
```

> but then after 2nd characters onward user can enter alpha,numeric and dash(-)

If this, however, means that any characters after the first dash character *must* be alphanumeric or a dash character, you'd need to use the following regular expression:

```
/^-[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$/
```

Like so:

```
/^-[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$/.test(myString);
```

Here's a [Regexper visualisation](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E-%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5C-%5D%2B%24%2F):

[image: Regexper Visualisation]

Comment: thanx for answere, but i need to use only regular expression for that not if condition.

Comment: @DharmendraJadav I've updated my answer with a regular expression. It's worth noting though that regular expressions aren't the be all and end all of string validation, and often aren't necessary.

Comment: @ James Donnelly thanx for agian answere i have one question if user enter only first character then it will not work - first character is dash(-)

Comment: @DharmendraJadav change the `+` symbol to a `*` symbol at the end. `+` means one or more; `*` means zero or more.

Comment: @DharmendraJadav no problem. Hit the tick beside my answer to mark it as accepted if you no longer require any answers. :)

Comment: hi james as per our previous communication please check your answere /^-[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+/.test(myString); it will allow @&* etc character after 2nd chracter but as per my comment it does not allowed

Comment: @DharmendraJadav whoops, that's because there's no `$` to denote the end of string at the end of the expression. I've updated the answer.

Comment: can you update answer for alphabet only in small character only using this expression

Comment: @DharmendraJadav get rid of the `A-Z` part if you only want lowercase.

Comment: using /^-[a-z0-9\-]+$/.test(myString); this expression ,i got wrong out put. it will not work on below example : (1) myString=aBc@#$%^&*  it will not work , i want disallow upperCase,Special characters in mystring , only allow 0-9,a-z and - dash symbol

Comment: @DharmendraJadav Not sure what you're doing wrong, but `/^-[a-z0-9\-]+$/.test("aBc@#$%^&*")` returns `false` as expected. Furthermore `/^-[a-z0-9\-]+$/.test("-abc")` returns `true`, as does `/^-[a-z0-9\-]+$/.test("-abc--")`, but `/^-[a-z0-9\-]+$/.test("-abc--A")` returns `false`. I believe this is the desired result?

Comment: /^-[a-z0-9\-]+$/.test("-aBc@#$%^&*")  this will return false but i want true , i needed user can enter "p5q4r-a1b2c"  means only digit ,alpha and -(dash) between two words